# Uniqueness of pure

Tags: haskell, applicative

For any `Applicative` instance, once `<*>` is written, `pure` is uniquely determined. Suppose you have `pure1` and `pure2`, both of which obey the laws. Then

```
pure2 f <*> pure1 y = pure1 ($ y) <*> pure2 f  -- interchange for pure1
pure2 id <*> pure1 y = pure1 ($ y) <*> pure2 id -- specialize f to id
pure1 y = pure1 ($ y) <*> pure2 id  -- identity for pure2
pure1 y = fmap ($ y) (pure2 id) -- applicative/fmap law for pure1
pure1 y = pure2 ($ y) <*> pure2 id -- applicative/fmap law for pure2
pure1 y = pure2 y -- homomorphism law
```

But using the `fmap` law this way feels like a cheat. Is there a way to avoid that without resorting to appeals to parametricity?

Comment: Intriguing. I'm sure something could be said about this in the light of `<*>` being not really the “fundamental” method of applicative, i.e. [_monoidal_ functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor) – it's rather `fzip :: f a -> f b -> f (a,b)`. However, I just don't quite get what you mean by “feels like a cheat”. You're just using the laws, how can that be a cheat.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I guess what I really mean is that the uniqueness of `fmap` (which implies the `fmap`/`Applicative` law) flows from parametricity. So if you take these laws out of a context where parametricity holds, that raises the question of whether `pure` is still determined by `<*>` or whether it's actually determined only by the combination of `fmap` with `<*>`.

Comment: I was also wondering how `fzip` and `funit :: f ()` might play into this sort of question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The laws as given in the current documentation do rely on parametricity to connect to `fmap`.

Without parametricity, we lose that connection, as we cannot even prove the uniqueness of `fmap`, and indeed there are models/extensions of System F where `fmap` is not unique.

A simple example of breaking parametricity is to add type-case (pattern-matching on types), this allows you to define the following `twist` which inspects the type of its argument and flip any boolean it finds:

```hs
twist :: forall a. a -> a
twist @Bool     = not
twist @(a -> b) = \f -> (\x -> twist @b (f (twist @a x)))
twist @a        = id  -- default case
```

It has the type of polymorphic identity, but it is `not` the identity function.

You can then define the following "twisted identity" functor, where `pure` applies `twist` to its argument:

```
newtype I a = I { runI :: a }

pure :: a -> I a
pure = I . twist

(<*>) :: I (a -> b) -> I a -> I b  -- The usual, no twist
(<*>) (I f) (I x) = I (f x)
```

A key property of `twist` is that `twist . twist = id`. This allows it to cancel out with itself when composing values embedded using `pure`, thus guaranteeing [the four laws of `Control.Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html). ([Proof sketch in Coq](https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/974eaad87a4e1173345bf385ebb0b050))

This twisted functor also yields a different definition of `fmap`, as `\u -> pure f <*> u`. Unfolded definition:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> I a -> I b
fmap f (I x) = I (twist (f (twist x)))
```

This does not contradict duplode's answer, which translates the usual argument for the uniqueness of the identity of monoids to the setting of monoidal functors, but it undermines its approach. The issue is that view assumes that you have a given functor already and that the monoidal structure is compatible with it. In particular, the law `fmap f u = pure f <*> u` is implied from defining `pure` as `\x -> fmap (const x) funit` (and `(<*>)` also accordingly). That argument breaks down if you haven't fixed `fmap` in the first place, so you don't have any coherence laws to rely on.

Comment: That's a very nicely presented example of parametricity breaking. When I originally wrote my answer, I hoped to keep an opening for not fully parametric functors which nonetheless would have an unique map function. The `funit`/`pure` connection doesn't tend to translate well to such settings, though.

Comment: " type-case (pattern-matching on types)" is that different to making `twist` a class/method and using `instances` to achieve pattern-matching on types?

Comment: Your `twist . twist = id` is similar to double `reverse`, in which `(reverse . f) . (reverse . g) =/= (reverse . (f . g))` over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135623/instance-signatures-constraints-on-methods?noredirect=1#comment116976051_66135623

Comment: you could use a class to define something similar but that seems besides the point of the question about parametricity and the Applicative class.

Comment: Why do you need to assume finiteness or extra machinery? Won't a default (identity) case do the trick?

Comment: I think a class should be fine. Either way, I think I get the drift, though I'd prefer an informal proof to one based on Coq tactics (which I don't know how to read).

Comment: Right, I include that mostly to say "someone did the proof at least once" and to avoid putting people who want to see the proof for themselves on a wild-goose chase.

Answer (score 6):

Let's switch to the monoidal functor presentation of applicative:

```
funit :: F ()
fzip :: (F a, F b) -> F (a, b)

fzip (funit, v) ~ v
fzip (u, funit) ~ u
fzip (u, fzip (v, w)) ~ fzip (fzip (u, v), w)
```

If we specialise `a` and `b` to `()` (and look past the tuple isomorphisms), the laws tell us that `funit` and `fzip` specify a monoid. Since the identity of a monoid is unique, `funit` is unique. For the usual `Applicative` class, `pure` can then be recovered as...

```
pure a = fmap (const a) funit
```

... which is just as unique. While in principle it makes sense to try to extend this reasoning to at least some functors that aren't fully parametric, doing so might require compromises in a lot of places:

- The availability of `()` as an object, to define `funit` and state the monoidal functor laws;
- The uniqueness of the map function used to define `pure` (see also [Li-yao Xia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66557122/2751851)), or, failing that, a sensible way to somehow uniquely specify a `fmap . const` analogue;
- The availability of function types as objects, for the sake of stating the `Aplicative` laws in terms of `(<*>)`.

Comment: So it sounds like the `Functor` instance may be necessary to link those presentations?

Comment: @dfeuer Perhaps that can be avoided. For instance, it *should* work fine with `Data.Set.map . const` instead of `(<$)`. The question which lies behind the "should", I guess, is what exactly does it take for there to be a sensible analogue of `(<$)` if we can't rely on parametricity. (By the way, note that, on second thought, I have somewhat weakened the closing words of the answer.)

Comment: @dfeuer In any case, `Data.Set` is a somewhat questionable example, as insisting on the `Ord` constraint costs us a straightforward analogue to `(<*>)`. It seems most examples I can think of are questionable in one way or another...